# GDP: business incorporation location vs citizenship criteria

Tags: gdp

Suppose a US citizen resides in Germany. He is a business-owner in Germany and the business is legally incorporated in Germany. However, he is a US citizen. The value of the good produced by this business will be part of Germany's GDP since they are produced in Germany. But do they count towards German GDP since he is a resident and the business is incorporated there, or towards US GDP since he is a US citizen?

Comment: you can google GDP vs GNP to answer that

Comment: not obvious since some places talk about residency criteria also while others talk about citizenship criteria... that's the reason for the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as this [question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/42216/37817). If in doubt, look at the source, not at textbooks or wherever.

In the US, that is [BEA](https://www.bea.gov/resources/methodologies/nipa-handbook/pdf/chapter-02.pdf).

Chapter 2: 2-6
Domestic measures cover activities that take place within the geographic
borders of the United States, while national measures cover activities that are attributable to U.S. residents. Footnote 17 accompanied with this statement defines that in detail.

“U.S. residents” includes individuals, governments, business enterprises, trusts, associations, nonprofit institutions, and similar organizations that have the center of their economic interest in the United States and that reside or expect to reside in the United States for 1 year or more. (For example, business enterprises residing in the United States include U.S. affiliates of foreign companies.) In addition, U.S. residents include all U.S. citizens who reside outside the United States for less than 1 year and U.S. citizens
residing abroad for 1 year or more who meet one of the following criteria: owners or employees of U.S. business enterprises who reside abroad to further the enterprises’ business and who intend to return within a reasonable period; U.S. government civilian and military employees and members of their immediate
families; and students who attend foreign educational institutions.

HTH

Comment: If you notice a duplicate please vote close question as a duplicate next time you have sufficient reputation to vote close on question